# Unable to locate persister for the entity named

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I am trying to connect to nHibernate but I did not do that. I have a configuration file which is look like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>   
    <property name="connection.connection_string_name">EMS</property>
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
    <property name="generate_statistics">true</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread_static</property>
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2012Dialect</property>
    <property name="cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
    <property name="cache.use_query_cache">false</property>
    <property name="default_schema">EMS.dbo</property>
    <property name="adonet.batch_size">200</property>
    <mapping assembly="EMS.Infra.Data"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and have a config file load method like below

//create instance for cfg

```
configuration = new Configuration(); // read config default style


configuration.AddAssembly(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());//forcely add mapping assembly

//add fluent auto mapping and conventions
                    Fluently.Configure(configuration).Mappings(m =>
                    m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Employee>().Conventions.Add(
                        PrimaryKey.Name.Is(x => "Id"),
                        ForeignKey.EndsWith("Id")));

                    //add dialect and connections strting
                    configuration.SessionFactory().Integrate.Using<MsSql2012Dialect>().Connected.ByAppConfing("EMS");//EMS is the connection name
```

My mapping file

```
public class EmployeeMap : ClassMap<Employee>
    {
        public EmployeeMap()
        {
            Table("HRM.Employee");
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().UnsavedValue(0);
            Map(x => x.LocationId);
            Map(x => x.SalutationId);
            Map(x => x.FirstName);
            Map(x => x.MiddleName);
            Map(x => x.LastName);
            Map(x => x.NickName);
            Map(x => x.EmpName);
        }
    }
```

When get data by this method
_session.Get(id);

The error has been occurred

> An exception of type 'NHibernate.HibernateException' occurred in
>   NHibernate.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to locate persister for the entity
>   named 'EMS.Domain.Hrm.Entities.Employee'.

Please give me any idea that will appreciate.

Comment: The exception say that the `Employee` is not mapped. Are the `Employee` and `EmployeeMap` in the same assembly?

Comment: Both are not same assembly

Comment: Thats the Problem. Exchange `m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Employee>()` with `EmployeeMap` instead of `Employee`, then it should work.

Comment: @Rabban, Same error.

Comment: Ok, but this is definitely an error. With `m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Employee>()` you have to tell him the Assembly of your mappings, not the assembly of your entities. Did you tried to remove the NHibernate config and tried to configure all with FluentNhibernate? Maybe there is some misconfiguration while mixing NHibernateConfig with FluentConfig.